# Cannot open uPVC Window

Tags: windows, pvc

Moved into a new house and a (fairly new) uPVC window will not open. I can unlock the the handle and it does not seem stuck -- but it will not open. It seem like something in the frame is stopping the window opening -- I can hear a tapping sound when I try.

It might be a safety feature, because the window is in the attic.

This video shows what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxU12.jpg

Any suggestions on how to open it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Silly thought:  Does it slide up?  (Hard to tell from the pictures).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't turning the handle far enough!

Comment: For those who haven't watched the video (or in case the video disappears) please [edit] your answer to indicate how far you did have to turn it. I presume 180°, but it's good to be explicit.